# Crud with FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, crud, fosuserbundle

I 'm a new with Symfony2!. Can you tell me please if I can user CRUD with FOSUserBundle?? Is that even possible ? Actually, i want create a Manager role who can edit and delete users form database !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FosUserBundle` doesn't provide such functionality. You can generate `CRUD` using `Symfony` standard edition built in task:

```
php app/console doctrine:generate:crud
```

for your `User` entity.

For more complex purposes you need to check some `admin` bundles, maybe [SonataAdminBundle](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/2-3/doc/index.html) . This will provide admin generator in which you can manage (`CRUD`) your entities.

Also note, that using all kinds of code generators is considered as not-so-good-practice

Comment: I have install FOSUserBundle then CRUD but now its not showing any field in CRUD /user/new

Comment: I also install FOSUserBundle then do the crud via command, but with the /user/new , there is no field.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are facing this issue :
- if you override the parent classe with custom fields (let's say "firstname" + "lastname") in you User entity 
- and then re-generate the CRUD

you will see that the 2 custom field became editable.

The Doctrine CRUD generator looks incompatible with FOSUserBundle in the present state, as we create inheritance with a User master class.

There is a same issue if you try to use the Group Model of FOSUserBundle.